# No Such File To Load Passenger and Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, passenger

I've recently updated to Ruby 1.9.2 (RVM), Sinatra 1.1 and Passenger 3.0.0. I have a simple application composed of:

```
# config.ru

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'app.rb'

run Sinatra::Application

# app.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

If I run the application from the terminal using `ruby app.rb` everythign launches as expected. However, with Passenger I get: `no such file to load -- app.rb`. I have other Rails applications running fine with the setup, and have setup the document root to a sub public directory. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem here:

```
# config.ru

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/app.rb"

run Sinatra::Application
```

Answer (score 9):

Managed to fix the issue. Figured out for some reason the `config.ru` requires the include to be specified relative to the current directory. The modified file is:

```
# config.ru

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './app.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Require paths are relative in ruby 1.9, except for installed gems which don't need a path.